# What does it mean when Discord.Net documentation says not to await a task that requests data?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am learning to develop Discord bots in C#.
https://discordnet.dev/guides/concepts/events.html
Under Safety, the documentation says "you should not await a task that requests data from Discord's gateway in the same context of an event".

I am assuming this means not to await such a task in the body of the delegate added to a discord event.
I am also assuming that a "task that requests data" includes downloading something from Discord servers.

Now, on the same page, at the bottom, the example they show does exactly what it says not to do. It awaits before.GetOrDownloadAsync() in the body of MessageUpdated.
Isn't that the same as requesting data.
So I guess my understanding of the statement was wrong. Can anyone explain what it means.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also somewhat new to Discord.net but I would say that the Documentation means to not use a non-async method to get the Data and that awaiting the async Download is ok cause you perhaps want to use the downloaded stuff right away.